# Does Promethean magic destroy items on the ground?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

AKA: "If I breathe fire on Diggles, will I charbroil my lutefisk bounty?"

As you can see, I've lucked into quite the lutefisk stockpile here:

[image]

My primary mode of diggle destruction, however, is to breathe a plume of all-consuming fire.  I've been trying to avoid using it around items to date, because I'm not sure if it causes damage to them - it tends to catch the stone floor on fire, and that makes me think it's a *serious* attack.  That lutefisk sure looks tasty, too...

Will I damage items on the floor if I use my fire breathing attack?  Are there any attacks which damage items on the floor?

Comment: I know what *most* of these words mean... But in combination... What.

Comment: I'm not certain enough of this to make it an answer, but I don't remember any attacks damaging items on the ground.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Ah, you seem to be in a state of dungeons of dredmor deprivation. I recommend obtaining said game and remedying this, stat!

Comment: In many other roguelike games (in particular Nethack and Angband), destructive area of effect could damage/destroy many items.  As mentioned, Dredmor doesn't have this feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. Your fiery breath will not consume items on the ground. Feel free to roast that diggle to your heart's content. Your valuable lutefisk will be fine.

Comment: The Lutefisk God will be pleased.  ALL HAIL THE LUTEFISK GOD!